# Return a value from xml to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have an XML file and program is in javascript/jquery. I am able to read the XML value but I cant get it to show it in HTML

```js
function readXMLnode(linktype, cdTicker) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "baird_Funds_BD.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(xml).find('Ticker').each(function() //find the ticker in xml 
          {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if (id == cdTicker) {
              $(this).load(linktype) {
                if (linktype == 'EmailAddress') {
                  $("Email Address").append("<li><a href='" + $(this).find("EmailAddress").text() + "'/></li>")
                }
              }
            }
          })
      })
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: Why are you doing a document ready inside a success method?  Rip that out.  It serves no purpose.  Also `$("Email Address")` is not a valid selector.  `$(this).attr('id')` can be just `this.id`.  `$(this).load(linktype) {` is most likely a syntax error.

Comment: when I remove the document ready it doesnt work. So far I get the program to refer to XML read whatever I want and open the specific URL. but in the case of the email address I just want it to read it and display it.

Comment: this is the HTML part  <li class="icon-mail"><a href="#"  onclick="readXMLnode('EmailAddress',cdTicker);">Email Address </a></li>

Answer (score 0):

`$("Email Address").append("<li><a href='" + $(this).find("EmailAddress").text() + "'/></li>")`

`$("Email Address")` is an invalid selector, use `$("#emailAddress")` or what have you instead